# convert this sql statement to rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM geo_blocks 
WHERE index_geo = INET_ATON("92.229.175.253")-(INET_ATON("92.229.175.253")%65536) 
AND INET_ATON("92.229.175.253") 
BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end;
```

How would I convert this to a rails format with something like this?

```
geodata = GeoBlocks.where(.......)
```

edit

This is what I ended up doing in the end.

```
require 'ipaddr'
ip = IPAddr.new("92.229.175.253")
geodata = GeoBlocks.where({:index_geo => (ip.to_i - (ip.to_i%(65536)))}, {:ip_start.lt => ip.to_i, :ip_end.gt => ip.to_i})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
geodata = GeoBlocks.where(
  "index_geo = INET_ATON(:ip)-(INET_ATON(:ip)%65536) AND INET_ATON(:ip) BETWEEN :ip_start AND :ip_end", {
    :ip        => "92.229.175.253",
    :ip_start  => ip_start,
    :ip_end    => ip_end
  }
)
```

Comment: Using the above code was not giving me the results I wanted as it was complaining about ip_start & ip_end. I ended up going with a different solution.